# Do broadcasted variables exist per node or per worker?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

#### Context:

- We have a large number of computations that all require the same **large immutable data structure** (a matrix) as input.
- To make this data structure available across nodes, I **broadcast** the matrix using: `matrix_future = client.scatter(matrix, broadcast=True)` and pass the `matrix_future` to delayed functions in the compute graph that require it. These functions are executed independently on different nodes.
- (for the sake of the question) let's assume we have 3 compute nodes: node1 runs the scheduler, node2 and node3 run 10 workers each.

#### Question:

- On the compute nodes running the workers (node2 and node3): does the broadcasted data structure exist only once in memory per node, or is there a copy per worker, thus 10 times the same data in the node's memory (1 per worker)?
- If it is shared, where does it reside on a node? Is there some object store from where it is accessible from the workers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data will exist within each dask worker process.  You will have ten copies on each node.

Dask workers operate completely independently.  They do not know of other workers that may be on the same node.

Instead, you might consider creating a single dask worker on each node that has ten threads.  This is often the right choice, especially if you're dealing with large numeric data.